# How to optimally save snapshots of two-dimensional array in sql database

Tags: sql, sql-server, relational-database

I have an data source that generates millions conditions of two-dimensional double array (matrix). The sizes of dimensions constantly change (but it's possible to simplify situation by mathematical transformation and allow only one dimension to change size). So, I need to save all states of this matrix into database (her approximate sizes are from 10x50 to 10x100 - the second dimension size changes with time). If I use time as primary key it means that I will have to create millions of tables, each of them will contain 10 columns and from 50 to 100 rows... It's not very convenient. Is there a way to more effectively group states of matrix? I'm new to SQL.

Comment: How do you want to access the data later? Do you need to find information based on what is stored in the matrix?

Comment: Primary Keys can be composite, so in this case a key of (Time,Row,Column) would be appropriate.

Comment: Yes, I need to analyze a sequence (about 500-1000 states) of matrix. I already thought about creating an additional column with time and collect states for one day in separate table (about 90 million states - it means from 90 * 50 millions rows to 90 * 100 millions rows) and collect states using time

Comment: It's awful, considering the fact that there are 30 matrixes, whos states must be observed. Yes, and I will have to add 2 columns it seems - time of state which will be the same for about 50-100 rows and row number for current state. Does SQL sequently SELECt rows from database?

Comment: Have you considered noSql databases? It would seem to be much more appropiate for your requirements.

Comment: And if you are going after just storing them, without not searching capabilities in the values stored in the matrix (just needs to retrieve them based in primary key or other identifiers), it might be worth to store it as some kind of JSON character in an individual field and parse/unparse the arrays when storing/retrieving them from the DB.

Answer (score 0):

how about a table having the following columns:

(id,) state_number, row, column, value

Comment: @Tyriar: He was suggesting something, not asking.

Comment: I recommend against using a key value type store fore this, as it there is a simpler solution available. This solution requires unnecessary syntactic and performance overhead.

Answer (score 0):

**Theory: How to use heavy tools (like MySQL)**

MySQL is commonly classified as a "heavy tool". Heavy tools solve a rather broad range of problems very well, but usually also have unique characteristics in terms of what they do well, poorly, or not at all. With all heavy tools, the challenge is to find the closest match between your problem and the heavy tool's peculiarities, and then bridge the gap in the simplest way possible. You are working on step 2.

**Solution step 1: The closest match between you and the tool**

The closest match I can come up with of your specific problem to MySQL's peculiarities is the same as yours: Tables that look like this.

columns:

```
id dataset_time col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7 col8 col9 col10

auto increment: id
primary key: id
```

**Solution step 2: Bridging the remaining gap**

However, creating one table per matrix is not the simplest way to bridge the remaining gap between your problem and what MySQL can do, as you have noticed. MySQL can create thousands of tables with a numeric index in the table name, but it would do so poorly.

The simplest way to bridge the gap is to introduce one additional column called dataset_id to make the table look like this:

columns:

```
id dataset_time col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7 col8 col9 col10 dataset_id

auto increment: id
primary key: id
non-unique index: dataset_id
```

You should manually increment the dataset id and insert it along which each row and the correspodning time. This is more robust than identifying each dataset by time.

Then you can retrieve datasets like this:

```
SELECT * FROM matrices WHERE dataset_id=761
```

MySQL has efficient indexing capabilities and elegant syntax for retrieving a couple of dozen rows from millions, so one can say it does so very well. So that is your optimal solution.